# Drupal: theming category pages

Tags: drupal

On a page like http://localhost/sitename/?q=category/tags/tag1 I've got a layout that's decided by page.tpl.php and then some more fine grained .tpl.php files.

For blogs I'm using page-blogs.tpl.php, for events I have events.tpl.php etc. How can I get a similar page just for the category url's? The reason is that this page.tpl.php is also used for other pages than the categories and I'd rather not put all kind of messy if/else in page.tpl.php

page-category.tpl.php doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Stef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the theamer part of the [devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel), that can show you the candidate templates used. That will give you an idea of what templates to use to override any part of your site.

Comment: +1 A good idea. Note that the devel module can sometimes wreck a site's theme messing up the layout or resulting in a blank screen. So don't use it while styling as it inserts a lot of <span> tags.

Comment: I've been using this module extensively but it seems category / tag pages are a bit of a special case. after alot of googling i ended up using page-taxonomy-term.tpl.php.

Answer (score 1):

Second @googletorp -- be careful with devel module as it has wrecked my site's layout in the past.